# Mono4Android Can't Find axml Resource

Tags: resources, find, xamarin.android

I'm trying to do the very basic tutorial on setting up multiple views on the Mono4Android Documentation. 
I've had this error for about 3 hours now, and can't seem to figure it out. 
I've looked through all the build settings ect but nothing...

Mono keeps coming up with the error : ".Resource.Layout Does not contain a definition for 'Second'"

I have even copied an pasted the whole tutorial, and yet I'm still idle from this pathetic error. 
I can dam right tell Mono that there is a definition of Second in the layout resource Folder!

Why doesn't anything want to play ball?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the [build action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) on the file is set to AndroidResource.

Comment: Oh, well done. Such a simple fix. I hope it wasn't a common question asked here from n00bs like myself, I did do a deep Google search :/